# How to set a Prawn::Table::Cell height?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn, prawnto

I am using prawn to generate pdfs and I am having problems when setting the cell height, I set the height but nothing happens. I am using like this:

```
mensagem_tabela = msg_nfe + "\n" + msg_numero + "\n" + msg_serie
tabela = Prawn::Table
tabela = [[Prawn::Table::Cell.new(:text => mensagem_tabela, :height => 5.cm)]]
@data = [[Prawn::Table::Cell.new(:text => msg, :font_size => 6), tabela]]
pdf.table @data, :width => 20.cm , :vertical_padding => 2, :column_widths => {0 => 15.5.cm}, :align => {1 => :center}
```

But when I see the result the height that is set is not printed in the pdf. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

Carlos,

> prawn v='0.11.1'

try changing

```
:height => 5.cm
```

to

```
:height => 50
```

I didn't test it myself, but I can confirm the height tag worked for me with that syntax (pixels not .cm)

Comment: Concur, that's what I'm using in my prawn file as well.

Comment: I just can set it to minimum `17`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You could also change `:height => 5.cm` to `:height => cm2pt(5)`

Reference the Prawn documentation here: http://rdoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn/Measurements